# Decode htmlEntities back on populate Zend Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element, html-entities

I decode my zend-form with htmlEntities. This works great, but I would like to decode the input back when I repopulate the form back to the user. Is there a way to reverse the setElementFilter in Zend?

Example:

User fills in input field with

```
You & me
```

Data placed in the database:

```
You &amp; me
```

I get the data back from the database and populate the input field with it:

```
You &amp;amp; me
```

I just want my ampersand (in this case) back and see this:

```
You & me
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to reverse the setElementFilter

No. You should filter your data with [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) before populating your form

Comment: That's all I wanted to know! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I usually repopulate my form if it was invalid or i wanted to edit some data

```
$form = new zend_form("name");
.......................
......................
$form->populate($this->_request->getAllparams());
```

or  if wanted to fill the form with custom data

```
$form->populate($data);
```

and zend form will take care of filtering , validating and populating the form back 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.forms.html

hope that would help